# Persistent volumes for Azure Openshift cluster

Tags: azure, openshift, persistent-storage, persistent-volumes, azure-files

I have an openshift 4.4 cluster hosted in Azure platform.

I have pods running as Deployments inside my cluster , now I need to make the container storage persistent to backup configurations inside those deployments.

I need to use Read/Write many mode for my requirement and I have 3 pods which needs to share the common persistant volume.

Currently I have admin access in Openshift console but didn't have any access in Azure directly.

I found that Azure file storage can serve my purpose but

I am not sure in how to achieve this persistent storage in Azure and openshift as I am new to both, can someone please guide me with any reference links or sample Yaml files to achieve this.

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Any more updates on the question? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks Charles, solved, would be great if you share the same problem solution for AWS EFS aswell, If you have any reference

Comment: I do not have experience with AWS EFS. I cannot provide a solution for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow the steps [here](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.4/storage/persistent_storage/persistent-storage-azure-file.html#create-azure-file-secret_persistent-storage-azure-file):

1. create a secret for the Azure Storage File Share;
2. create a persistent volume with the secret;
3. create a persistent volume claim for the persistent volume
4. associate the persistent volume claim to the pod

And for the Azure File **StorageClass**, you can see the example [here](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.5/storage/dynamic-provisioning.html#azure-file-definition_dynamic-provisioning).

Comment: can you please give reference like the above for Azure blob storage aswell.

Comment: @Balakrishna As I know, it seems it does not support azure blob storage currently.

Comment: can you please give me any reference to prove that azure blob is not supported. I mean I need some reference to confirm exactly, Please If you could

Comment: @Balakrishna You cannot find the azure blob storage in the support area. It already means it.

Comment: can you please comment on this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65137145/network-policy-in-kubernetes-not-working-in-different-namespaces

Comment: @Balakrishna I will take a look.